# Integration by parts of $\sin(x)e^x$

Tags: integration, analysis, trigonometry

I'm studying analysis and I have a problem with the integral calculation of this function:

$$\int \sin(x)e^x\mathrm dx$$

I start by using integration by parts and I obtained this:

$$\int \sin(x)e^x\mathrm dx = \sin(x)e^x-\int \cos(x)e^x\mathrm dx$$

But now I don't know how to continue, will I enter in a infinite loop if I repeat integration by parts?

I do it one more time like the comment above said and I have:

$$\int \sin(x)e^x\mathrm dx = \sin(x)e^x-\cos(x)e^x-\int -\sin(x)e^x\mathrm dx$$

And if I move to the left I obtain:

$$\int \sin(x)e^x\mathrm dx+\int -\sin(x)e^x\mathrm dx = \sin(x)e^x-\cos(x)e^x$$

Right?

Comment: Just do it one more time......

Comment: and rearrange, put the integral to the left hand side.

Comment: Hey, you're done. just put that $\int sinx.e^x$ in the left side

Comment: Do you mean $\int -sinx*e^xdx$?

Comment: No, wrong, you have a sign error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going well, just do the next thing:

$\int\sin(x)e^xdx = \sin(x)e^x - \cos(x)e^x - \int\sin(x)e^xdx \rightarrow
2\int\sin(x)e^xdx =sin(x)e^x - cos(x)e^x \rightarrow \int\sin(x)e^xdx=\frac{1}{2}(\sin(x)e^x - \cos(x)e^x) $

Comment: But I have $\int -sinxe^xdx$ and not $\int sinxe^xdx$

Comment: The problem is that when you have made the integral by parts the second time you did not take the sign into account: $\int\sin(x)e^xdx=    \sin(x)e^x-(\cos(x)e^x -\int(-\sin(x)e^xdx)$

Comment: Thanks I found the error :)

Answer (score 3):

Another way could be to consider $$I=\int \sin(x)\,e^x\,dx$$ $$J=\int \cos(x)\,e^x\,dx$$ Then $$J+i I=\int e^{ix}\,e^x\,dx=\int e^{(1+i)x}\,dx=\frac { e^{(1+i)x}} {1+i}=\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right) e^{(1+i) x}$$ Expand the last term to get $$J+i I=\frac{1}{2} e^x \sin (x)+\frac{1}{2} e^x \cos (x)+i \left(\frac{1}{2} e^x \sin
   (x)-\frac{1}{2} e^x \cos (x)\right)$$

Doing the same for $$K=\int \sin(ax)\,e^{bx}\,dx$$ $$L=\int \cos(ax)\,e^{bx}\,dx$$ $$L+iK=\int e^{iax}e^{bx}\,dx=\int e^{(b+ia)x}dx=\frac {e^{(b+ia)x}}{b+ia}=\frac {b-ia}{a^2+b^2}{e^{(b+ia)x}}$$ and expanding again $$L+iK=\frac{a e^{b x} \sin (a x)}{a^2+b^2}+\frac{b e^{b x} \cos (a x)}{a^2+b^2}+i
   \left(\frac{b e^{b x} \sin (a x)}{a^2+b^2}-\frac{a e^{b x} \cos (a
   x)}{a^2+b^2}\right)$$

Comment: I thank you for the help but this is a very difficult procedure for me, but thanks :)

Comment: @SimoneC.. You are welcome ! When you will learn about complex numbers and their represntation, try to remember the trick. You will later see how simple and usefule this could be. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

### Another way to do this question

---

$$I=\int\frac{1}{2}e^x(\sin x -\cos x +\cos x +\sin x)$$
$$=\int \frac{1}{2}e^x(f(x) +f'(x))$$

Answer (score 0):

**By indeterminate coefficients**:

Seeing the expressions obtained by parts, you are hinted to try a solution of the form

$$(a\cos x+b\sin x)e^x.$$

After differentiation,

$$((a+b)\cos x+(b-a)\sin x)e^x.$$

Then by identification

$$\begin{cases}a+b=0,\\a-b=-1\end{cases}$$ is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that

$$(\sin x\,e^x)'=(\sin x+\cos x)e^x=\sqrt2\sin\left(x+\frac\pi4\right)e^x.$$

From this,

$$(\sin x\,e^x)''=\left(\sqrt2\sin\left(x+\frac\pi4\right)e^x\right)'={\sqrt2}^2\sin\left(x+2\frac\pi4\right)e^x$$

and by induction

$$(\sin x\,e^x)^{(k)}={\sqrt2}^k\sin\left(x+k\frac\pi4\right)e^x.$$

gives the $k^{th}$ derivative.

Similarly, $k=-1$ corresponds to the antiderivative

$$\int\sin x\,e^x\,dx=\sqrt2^{-1}\sin\left(x-\frac\pi4\right)e^x=\frac12(\sin x-\cos x)e^x+C.$$

For other negative $k$, you get the $k^{th}$ antiderivatives (plus a polynomial).

Answer (score -1):

Let $\int\sin xe^x = I$.

$I = \sin xe^x - \cos xe^x -I$

$2I = \sin xe^x - \sin xe^x$

$I = (\sin xe^x - \cos xe^x)/2.$